# How does TThread.Synchronize() work?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I tested the following code with the `Synchronize()` method in C++Builder 2010:

```
while(true) {}
CreateDirectory ("D:\\test", NULL);
```

What happened is that the UI freezed, and the folder was not created. Does that means that `Synchronize()` passes the code to the UI thread to execute it, and then waits until the code is executed before continuing?

---

**Edit:**

I explained wrongly what I have done in my test code. What I have really done is the following:

I called `Synchronize()` with the following code:

```
while(true) {}
```

And after calling `Synchronize()`, I had the following code:

```
CreateDirectory ("D:\\test", NULL);
```

Comment: Did you read the docs? It will answer your question

Comment: I love this advice in the documentation, "If you are unsure whether a method call is thread-safe, call it from within the Synchronize method to ensure that it executes in the main thread." The tell tale sign of having been written by a developer that codes that way. "Hmm, I don't really know what this function does, but rather than work it out, I'll just stuff it inside a Synchronize call!"

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yeah, when a proper documentation would be "Don't use Synchronize, use Queue."

Comment: Recommended reading: [Multithreading - The Delphi Way](http://thaddy.co.uk/threads/) by Martin Harvey

Comment: did you really mean to write {} behind while? This will simply create an endless loop and CreateDirectory will never be called. Maybe put the closing curly bracket after the CreateDirectory?

Comment: @gabr Why would `Synchronize()` exists if you should not use it? `Synchronize()` has its uses (e.g. to make sure that the supplied function has finished executing before returning).

Comment: @paul Because Synchronize typically occurs in a badly designed program. If your background thread depends on blocking and waiting on GUI, you are almost always doing something wrongly.

Comment: A comment to answer #1 links to "Multithreading - The Delphi Way. Martin Harvey." The link is broken, but the author has both a link to the original webpages and an updated version 2 posted in January 2017. http://www.martincharvey.tk/?cat=4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does that means that Synchronize() passes the code to the UI thread to execute it, and then waits until the code is executed before continuing?

Yes. This is in fact described in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize):

> Executes a method call within the main thread.
>
> Synchronize causes the call specified by AMethod to be executed using
>   the main thread, thereby avoiding multithread conflicts. The AThread
>   parameter associates the caller thread.
>
> For static methods, you can associate AMethod with any thread using
>   the AThread parameter. Also, you can use nil/NULL as AThread parameter
>   if you do not need to know the information for the caller thread in
>   the main thread.
>
> In the current implementation, the Synchronize method can use
>   associated thread information to wake-up the main thread on Windows
>   platforms.
>
> If you are unsure whether a method call is thread-safe, call it from
>   within the Synchronize method to ensure that it executes in the main
>   thread.
>
> Execution of the current thread is suspended while the method executes
>   in the main thread.

Your infinite loop is therefore blocking the main thread. And indeed the worker thread.

Comment: Does it use `SendMessage()` or `PostMessage()` to do that?

Comment: It depends on the platform. Certainly on some Windows versions, in some scenarios, `PostMessage` is used to wake the main thread. For instance, if the main thread is a VCL thread, then `TApplication.WakeMainThread` is called which does this: `PostMessage(Handle, WM_NULL, 0, 0)`.

Comment: Elaborating on this a little, `TThread` is cross-platform now and so has to work on platforms that don't have the Windows message queue. Clearly they don't use `PostMessage`. Likewise programs with no message queue, e.g. console apps, have to wake the main thread in a different way. The `WakeMainThread` global var `Classes` is the mechanism that allows main thread waking behaviour to be varied.

Comment: When using this code: `PostMessage(Handle, WM_NULL, 0, 0)`, that means that the function pointer (for the code I want to execute in the UI thread) is not sent along with the message. So what happens when I call `Synchronize()` is that it places the function pointer in some memory location, and then calls `PostMessage(Handle, WM_NULL, 0, 0)`, and then in the UI thread, the Window Procedure handles the `WM_NULL` message by getting the function pointer from this memory location and executing it, and when done it signals the worker thread to wake up. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: That's it essentially. The `WM_NULL` is just to wake the UI thread up in case it is blocking for messages. When it wakes up the message loop code checks to see if there are any Synchronize events to handle.

Comment: @paul: Yes, that is essentially what it does. The `Classes` unit has an internal list that `TThread.Synchronize()` and `TThread.Queue()` both add an item to, and in the case of `Synchronize()` it waits for that item to be signaled. When the main message loop is "woken up", and also when the main message loop goes "idle" after it finishes processing pending messages, the main thread calls the `Classes.CheckSynchronize()` function, which runs through that list, executing and signaling each item as needed.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau So `Synchronize()` adds the function pointer to this internal list and also adds an event that is associated with this function pointer to signal when this function is executed in the UI thread. and on the `WM_NULL` event in the UI thread, the `Classes.CheckSynchronize()` function is called, which fetches the function pointer and the event associated with it from this internal list, execute the function, and then signal the event to wake up the worker thread. correct?

Comment: @paul: Yes, that is correct. And `Synchronize()` waits on the event after adding the item to the list. And just for added measure, `CheckSynchronize()` catches any uncaught exception that is raised by the function, stores the exception object in the list item, and then `Synchronize()` raises that object within its own context after the event has been signaled. So a thread can still perform their own exception handling on synced functions. Look, if you really want to learn the gritty details, all you have to do is open the RTL's `Classes.pas` source file in a text editor and read it.