# ZXing.Delphi - Correct use of TThread.Synchronize?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, firemonkey, zxing

I'm starting a project for barcode reading in a FMX/Android app (new to barcode reading, I've some experience with FMX).

I found this open-source [ZXing.Delphi library](https://github.com/Spelt/ZXing.Delphi) (greatly helpful) and I went through the code of [this example](https://github.com/Spelt/ZXing.Delphi/tree/v_3.0/aTestApp).

I may not be used enough to `TThread` but I'm wondering on the use of `TThread.Synchronize` in this case, because I have never seen/used it like this before.

1 - The function responsible for capturing + scanning an image in search of a barcode is `GetImage`. It is sync'd to main thread on `CameraComponent1SampleBufferReady`.

```
procedure TMainForm.CameraComponent1SampleBufferReady(Sender: TObject;
  const ATime: TMediaTime);
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread, GetImage);
end;
```

2 - `GetImage` function contains `TTask.Run` which again makes use of `TThread.Synchronize` to sync to the main thread.

```
procedure TMainForm.GetImage;
var scanBitmap: TBitmap; ReadResult: TReadResult;
begin

  CameraComponent1.SampleBufferToBitmap(imgCamera.Bitmap, True);

...

  scanBitmap := TBitmap.Create();
  scanBitmap.Assign(imgCamera.Bitmap);
  ReadResult := nil;

  // There is bug in Delphi Berlin 10.1 update 2 which causes the TTask and
  // the TThread.Synchronize to cause exceptions.
  // See: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16377

  TTask.Run(
  procedure
  begin
    try
      FScanInProgress := True;
      try
        ReadResult := FScanManager.Scan(scanBitmap);
      except
        on E: Exception do
        begin
          TThread.Synchronize(nil,
          procedure
          begin
            lblScanStatus.Text := E.Message;
          end);

          exit;
        end;
      end;

      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
      procedure
      begin

        ...

        if (ReadResult <> nil) then
        begin
          Memo1.Lines.Insert(0, ReadResult.Text);
        end;

      end);

    finally
      ReadResult.Free;
      scanBitmap.Free;
      FScanInProgress := false;
    end;

  end);

end;
```

**? :** Is it usual/good pratice to encapsulate TThread.Synchronize( TTask.Run( TThread.Synchronize(...) ) ); ?

**? :** Couldn't it be the cause of the mentionned exceptions encountered in Delphi 10.1 update 2 ?

When I "learned" to use Parallel Programming Library, I mainly used :

- [this entry on Emb'ro](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Using_the_Parallel_Programming_Library)
- [Malcolm Groves' blog](http://www.malcolmgroves.com/blog/?cat=123)
- [this CodeRage 9 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLwUPJvR9mZHhgQYWWgF6BCkgDwIpP78ZV&v=rZfux4by0po)

Did I missed it somewhere ?

Comment: I would not wrap `TTask.Run` inside of `TThread.Synchronize`, but it should work OK. Typically, only UI access needs to be synched (`CameraComponent1.SampleBufferToBitmap`, `Memo1.Lines.Insert`, etc). I believe the `TBitmap` access also needs to be synched, due to bugs in FMX's handling of bitmaps. That should be fixed in a future update.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It does work OK. I now understand that `CameraComponent1.SampleBufferToBitmap` or `scanBitmap.Assign` need to run in the main thread, but don't need to `Synchronize`, if not in `TTask` of course. Thank you for the light shed here. I also found some in [a related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29686543/how-does-tthread-synchronize-work). And citing Embarcadero :
[Warning: Do not call Synchronize from within the main thread. This can cause an infinite loop.](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize)

Comment: You can ignore that warning, it is wrong. There Is no loop. I don't know why they ever wrote that.

Answer (score 0):

A quick update. With Embarcadero 10.3.1:

```
TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread, GetImage);
```

generates after a random number of seconds a Segmentation Fault.
You can notice a many "Switch To Thread" calls suring debug and it will always crash the APP.
No matter if you leave GetImage function empty.
I've tried all the possibile ways but my app and also the original app crashes.
I've also tried creating an Asyincronous thread as well as Labda... same results all the times
It looks like TThread Synchronization has issues on 10.3.1. Other users reported to have it working fine on previous Tokyo version.

Any feedback from your side?

Comment: I have not yet worked with Delphi 10.3.1. Have you tried try run the app on different operating system versions ? Did you try to use TThread.Queue in place of TThread.Synchronize ?

Comment: I have not tried yet. I tried to run the orignal App by Embarcadero and the problem is the same.

I tried the aCamera component from Winsoft and it works file!
**This is definetely an issue with Embarcadero Rio 10.3.1 Camera Component and Thread Syncronize / Queue and such.**
Again somebody reported that this problem was not present in previous versions!